# Difference in output from use of synchronized keyword and join()

Tags: java, multithreading, join, synchronized

I have 2 classes,

```
public class Account {
private int balance = 50;

public int getBalance() {
    return balance;
}
public void withdraw(int amt){
    this.balance -= amt; } }
```

and

```
public class DangerousAccount implements Runnable{
private Account acct = new Account();   

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    DangerousAccount target = new DangerousAccount();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(target);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(target);

    t1.setName("Ravi");
    t2.setName("Prakash");
    t1.start();
/* #1 t1.join(); */
    t2.start();
}

public void run(){
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        makeWithdrawl(10);
        if(acct.getBalance() < 0)
            System.out.println("Account Overdrawn");
    }
}
  public void makeWithdrawl(int amt){
        if(acct.getBalance() >= amt){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is going to withdraw");
            try{
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            acct.withdraw(amt);
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has finished the withdrawl");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Not Enough Money For " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " to withdraw");
}
  }
}
```

I tried adding synchronized keyword in makeWithdrawl method

`public synchronized void makeWithdrawl(int amt){`

and I keep getting this output as many times I try

```
Ravi is going to withdraw
Ravi has finished the withdrawl
Ravi is going to withdraw
Ravi has finished the withdrawl
Ravi is going to withdraw
Ravi has finished the withdrawl
Ravi is going to withdraw
Ravi has finished the withdrawl
Ravi is going to withdraw
Ravi has finished the withdrawl
Not Enough Money For Prakash to withdraw
Not Enough Money For Prakash to withdraw
Not Enough Money For Prakash to withdraw
Not Enough Money For Prakash to withdraw
Not Enough Money For Prakash to withdraw
```

This shows that only Thread t1 is working...

If I un-comment the the line saying

```
t1.join();
```

and remove the synchronized keyword from makeWithdrawl method, I get the same output.

If I don't use synchronize keyword or join() I get various outputs like

```
Ravi is going to withdraw
Prakash is going to withdraw
Prakash has finished the withdrawl
Ravi has finished the withdrawl
Prakash is going to withdraw
Ravi is going to withdraw
Prakash has finished the withdrawl
Ravi has finished the withdrawl
Prakash is going to withdraw
Ravi is going to withdraw
Prakash has finished the withdrawl
Ravi has finished the withdrawl
Account Overdrawn
Account Overdrawn
Not Enough Money For Ravi to withdraw
Account Overdrawn
Not Enough Money For Prakash to withdraw
Account Overdrawn
Not Enough Money For Ravi to withdraw
Account Overdrawn
Not Enough Money For Prakash to withdraw
Account Overdrawn
```

So how does the output from synchronized differ from join() ?
And do we ever need to add the synchronized keyword to run() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

synchronized will not allow other thread to access same resource at the same time.

```
synchronized method(){
      allowed one Thread at a time.
}
```

join will wait for child thread to complete execution.

```
Parent Thread started.

       Child Thread started

Parent Thread is Completed but waiting for Child Thread to complete .
      Child Thread Completed 
Parent Thread Completed
```

Answer (score 1):

> So how does synchronized differ from join() ?

They do completely different things. `synchronized` is used to prevent two threads from executing synchronized regions of code at once -- in your specific case it prevents both threads from running `makeWithdrawl()` at the same time (one will wait for the other if they get there at the same time). `Thread.join()` waits for a thread to exit -- in your specific case this waits for `t1` to finish completely before starting `t2`. They are apples and oranges.

I recommend consulting the documentation on each:

- [Synchronized methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)
- [`Thread.join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29)

Also here is a good, official tutorial on concurrency:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Work through that and it will clear up a lot of your questions.

> So how does the output from synchronized differ from join() ?

You already seem to have answered this question in your post; you can clearly see the difference in output.